# Incorrect URL from AWS S3 with Laravel File Upload

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I'm uploading an image to S3 with Laravel as follows:

```
$image = $request->image;

if (!empty($image)) {
   $imageFileName = $user_id.'_'.rand(11111111, 99999999) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); // Rename Image

try
{
   //Send to S3
   $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
   $filePath = '/profile/' . $imageFileName;
   $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');  
   $image = Storage::cloud()->url($imageFileName);

 }
catch(\Exception $exx)
 {
   //Send to Logs Etc
 }
```

The image uploads successfully but I need to store the URL in my database. This is being called here:

```
$image = Storage::cloud()->url($imageFileName);
```

The issue is the URL being returned, it looks like this:

http://test-env.XXX.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/profile/https://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-123XXX456XXX.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/6_52644340.jpg

Hence:

http://mentr-test-env.2w8sh3esch.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/profile/

is somewhat-correct. But the next piece is missing the 'profile' sub-folder, and obviously starts at HTTPS again:

https://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-123XXX456XXX.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/6_52644340.jpg

It would appear I'm getting two halves of the link in a single string. I don't edit the $image variable anywhere else.

The correct link is:

https://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-123XXX456XXX.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/profile/6_52644340.jpg

I have confirmed the files are uploading correctly and publicly available.

I have tried calling:

```
$image = Storage::cloud()->url($filePath);
```

And this returns:

http://test-env.XXXX.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/profile/https://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-XXX123XXX.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com//profile/6_31595766.jpg

**Update**

I just noticed the first part of the returned URL is the BeanStalk instance URL with the /profile/ added. This is even stranger as I don't wish to use Beanstalk, I only want to use S3.

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = $request->image;

if (!empty($image)) {
   $imageFileName = $user_id.'_'.rand(11111111, 99999999) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); // Rename Image

try
{
   //Send to S3
   $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
   $filePath = '/profile/' . $imageFileName;
   $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');  
   $image = Storage::cloud()->url('s3-url/s3-bucket'.'/'.$filepath);

 }
catch(\Exception $exx)
 {
   //Send to Logs Etc
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store the entire url you can get it from the return variable passed back from the `put()` function.

```
$s3_url = $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
```

Sometimes I like to just store the path though and save just that piece to the database then I can pass the path to `Storage::url($filePath);` and it still works.